# onsenui with Cordova - start application on specific screen

Tags: ios, cordova, reactjs, monaca, onsen-ui2

I'm running a React.js/Cordova/OnsenUI application that is intended to be used both in the browser and on mobile devices.  I'd like the user to be able to scan a QR code, then jump to a screen in my application.

This is what the application looks like right now:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  Navigator
} from 'react-onsenui';

import MainPage from './MainPage';
import Vendor from './Vendor';    

const renderPage = (route, navigator) => (
  <route.component key={route.key} navigator={navigator} />
);

const App = () => (
  <Navigator
    renderPage={renderPage}
    initialRoute={{component: MainPage, key: 'MAIN_PAGE'}}
  />
);

export default App;
```

When I start up, depending on the URL, I might want to start with a `Vendor` component or a `MainPage` component.

I figured that the easiest thing to do would be to dynamically create the `initialRoute` object based on the QR code that was scanned.  Given that I might be on an iOS device, how do I know what the URL was that was scanned?  Is there a different way that I should be jumping to a specific screen when I start the app?